# How to do curves in a mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I am trying to achieve a curve on my mesh. Mainly I am trying to make a dog bowl. I can't seem to understand how to do the curve for the bowl for both the inside and the odd lip thing on the outside ends.

It should be noted that I am a newbie to Blender, I have taken the fundamentals course here: [CG Cookie Mesh Fundamentals](https://cgcookie.com/course/mesh-modeling-fundamentals/) but didn't see anything on curving a mesh. Unless its a mixture of extruding, subdividing etc that I am missing.

My current attempts have been using insets and transforming downward. But this gives a cone shape instead. Any pointers?

This is my template of what I am trying to replicate in blender. 
[image: Dog bowl]

Comment: You can do this with a screw modifier

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera please elaborate.

Comment: elaborated... Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should be easily accomplished with a screw modifier.

all you need to do is create the profile of the dog bowl.

[image]

Once you do, it will be imperative to put the vertex that marks the center of the bowl on the origin of the object. you can do this by selecting this vertex and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>>*Cursor to selected* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>>*origin to 3D cursor*

Now add the screw modifier. you can set the amount of turn it goes for higher detail.

[image]

[image]